# Calculate Bitwise Operators Value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a ranks collection with a permissions field which are bitwise operators:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "xxxx",
    "name": "Rank 1",
    "permissions": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Rank 2",
    "permissions": 2
  }
]
```

Example users:

```json
[
   {
      "_id":"1234",
      "ranks":[
         "xxxx",
         "xxxxxxxxx"
      ]
   }
]
```

The users collection containts a `ranks` value, which stores an array of the rank ids.

I'm wanting to get the user, and their ranks and set their permissions to a value.

```js
const users = await this.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { userID: '123' }
    },
    { $limit: 1 },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'ranks',
            localField: 'rank',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'ranks'
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            permissions: {
                $arrayElemAt: ['$rank.permissions', 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$rank',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    }
]).toArray();
```

This obviously gets 1 value from the collection, I'm wanting to get all permissions and add the bitwise operators together.

Expected Output

```json
{
   "_id": "1234",
   "ranks":[
        "xxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxx"
   ]
   "permissions":3
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would you clarify exactly what you want as output and show an example doc from the users collection?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have updated the post, hopefully that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: In your `"$set"`, could you just use [`"$sum"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), like `"$set": {"permissions": {"$sum": "$ranks.permissions"}}`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don't think this would work if there was duplicated permissions, it would need some sort of logic working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to "or" all the rank permissions by using a server-side javascript `"$function"`.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 42
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ranks",
      "localField": "ranks",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "permissions": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "permissions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "permissions": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(perms) {return perms.reduce((prevV, currV) => prevV | currV, 0)}",
          "args": ["$permissions.permissions"],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/99AOGTM5Fqc).

Answer (score 0):

With sample collection...

```
db = {
  "permissions": [
    {
      "_id": "xxxx",
      "name": "Rank 1",
      "permissions": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "Rank 2",
      "permissions": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "xxxxxxx",
      "name": "Rank 4",
      "permissions": 4
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": "1234",
      "ranks": [
        "xxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "4567",
      "ranks": [
        "xxxx",
        "xxxxxxx"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

...try the following aggregation, which...

- Finds the `_id` for the user `1234` in the `users` collection.
- Looks for all the corresponding ranks in the `permissions` collection.
- Unwinds to have one result per corresponding permission.
- Aggregates the permissions and ranks.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": "1234"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "permissions",
      localField: "ranks",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "ranks"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$ranks"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      ranks: {
        $push: "$ranks._id"
      },
      permissions: {
        $sum: "$ranks.permissions"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See MongoDB playground at...

- https://mongoplayground.net/p/BCl57dNhupH

**Important Note:**  This query groups the permissions by sum (rather than by boolean logical OR), so you must ensure that there are no duplicate permissions.  If you can't ensure unique permissions per user, then suggest that the `permissions` are `$push`ed like the `ranks`, and then perform some post processing on the list of `permissions` to reduce via logical OR...